# How to validate multidimensional array in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate, zend-filter

I am wondering what is the best way to validate multidimensional array using `Zend_Validate` with `Zend_FilterInput`.

Here is my current code:

```
$filters = array(
    'symbol'        => array('StripTags', 'StringTrim'),
    'mode'          => array('StripTags', 'StringTrim'),
);
$validators = array(
    'symbol'        => array('NotEmpty'),
    'mode'          => array('NotEmpty'),
);


$input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $_POST);
```

I would like to append here an array, for example `name[]` array (posting an array with two/three names).

Here is a sample `$_POST` array:

```
array(
    'symbol' => 'SD34G',
    'mode'   => 'back',
    'name'   => array(
                       0 => 'Name A',
                       1 => 'Name B',
                       2 => 'Name C'
                )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found that I should do it for an array with the same method as for string.

`Zend_Filter_Input` checks if value is array and does `foreach` with validating every its element.

So....

```
$filters = array(
    'symbol'        => array('StripTags', 'StringTrim'),
    'mode'          => array('StripTags', 'StringTrim'),
    'name'          => array('StripTags', 'StringTrim'),
);
$validators = array(
    'symbol'        => array('NotEmpty'),
    'mode'          => array('NotEmpty'),
    'name'          => array('NotEmpty'),
);
```

;-)